# Cplex: Maximizing satisfied demand

Tags: java, cplex

I have a function that describes a satisfied request. The value is '1' whenever all conditions are met:
[image]

This expression is for a single set of conditions. My objective is to maximize the sum of Sd across all possible sets of conditions.
How can I write such an objective function?

I'm working on the Cplex Java API (IloCplex).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried indicator constraints (ifThen), but couldn't find a proper way to use them for the objective

Comment: Try breaking the problem down into smaller steps. Try creating some extra variables to hold the 1/0 values for each Sd (maybe using indicator constraints) and check that they behave correctly. Then build your objective function frm those extra variables.